# Can someone help me debug this error: Undefined offset: 0?

Tags: php

I am creating a function that calculate the quantity of sold tickets, and here is my code:

```
public function get_quantity($tickets_info){
    $i = 0; //$i is the starting point of the loop
    $k = 0;
    $Qty = 1; // this is used to save the quantity of tickets, by default there is always one ticket
    $index = array();
    $quantity = array();
    for($j = 1; $j < count($tickets_info); $j++) {
//            if the ticket_id are the same, then increase the quantity by one
        if($tickets_info[$i]['ticket_id'] == $tickets_info[$j]['ticket_id'])
        {
            $Qty++;
        }
//            if the ticket_id are not the same, then push the quantity into an array and remember the index
        else
        {
            $idx = $j;//remember the index of the next first different ticket_id
            $i = $j;//find the next starting point
            $index[$k] = $idx;//push back the index of the next different ticket_id
            $quantity[$k] = $Qty;//save quantity into the array
            $k++;//increase the index poniter
            $Qty = 1;//reset quantity back to one
        }
    }
//        push the last quantity into the array
    $quantity[$k+1] = $Qty;

    //assign the ticket information into a new array
    for($m = 0; $m < count($quantity); $m++){
        $ticket[$m] = $tickets_info[$m]; 
    }

    //create the finally array, combine ticket information with quantity
    $n = 0;
    foreach($ticket as $row)
    {
        $row['Qty'] = $quantity[$n++];
    }

    return $ticket;

}
```

`$ticket_info` is a 2-D array which is generated from a SQL, and it has a structure like this:

```
$ticket_info
(
    [0]=>array
    (
        [ticket_id] => 0001
        [purchase_time] => 2014/01/02
        ....

    )
    [1]=>array
    (
        [ticket_id] => 0001
        [purchase_time] => 2014/01/02
        ....

    )
    [2]=>array
    (
        [ticket_id] => 0001
        [purchase_time] => 2014/01/02
        ....

    )
    ....
)
```

Basically, if the tickets have the same `ticket_id` that means they have been bought at the same time (but in the database, I recorded them separately for a specific purpose), so I need to add them up and get the quantity.

I'm not familiar with PHP arrays, so I write my algorithm in C++ and tested it. It works fine. However, when I tried to write the real code in PHP, I got 2 errors:

For line, `$ticket[$m] = $tickets_info[$m];` Message: Undefined offset: 0

For line, `$row['Qty'] = $quantity[$n++];`  Message: Undefined offset: 0

I don't know why there is no index 0, maybe I didn't initialize the array correctly or I didn't pass the data in `$ticket_info` in the right format? Can someone help me look at this code?

Comment: so `var_dump($ticket, $tickets_info)` and see what you're really dealing with. undefined offset means you're tryign to access a numerical index that doesn't exist.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the advice. `$ticket_info` is null. I didn't pass that data successfully into the function

Answer (score 1):

Do a check before you try access that index:

```
if (!empty($ticket) && !empty($tickets_info)) {
    $ticket[$m] = $tickets_info[$m];
}
```